# Retrieving a random record from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

Wondering what is the best way to retrieve a random record from the database in my Ruby on Rails (2.3.9) applications.

The closest I got was using the below. SQLITE3 liked it by in production MySQL did not.

```
#class PostsController < ApplicationController
...
@posts = Post.all(:order => "RANDOM()")
...
end

#view
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is `RAND()` in MySQL.  Use it instead of `RANDOM()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL query works fine for me on MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

<strike>I'm not sure what the rails equivalent of this, but you get the idea</strike>

I'll take a guess that the Rails equivalent of above SQL would be:

```
Post.all(:order => "rand()", :limit => 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible depending on the scope of your problem and the size of your database.  See [Axiom of Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice).  ;)

Comment: There is a lot of undefined-ness in that answer.